# IntelliJ IDEA method too long

Tags: methods, intellij-idea

I'm making an iPhone game in .lua using IntelliJ IDEA, and I have a function after each level that clears all the stuff off the screen. On level three however, the name of the method is underlined in white and it says:

> Method "WipeOut3" is too long (statement count = 37 > 30)

Are there any ramifications to this? This is the first I've ever heard of a method having a maximum length, especially not 30 statements! Should I be worried? Should I just split the method in half and run two shorter methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this message is from a code quality analysis tool. This indicates that method has more *statements* then some predefined value which is considered adequate. Methods which are long and complex are usually hard to understand and, again, usually, indicate bad code design. But it's all up to you should you consider these suggestions or not.

Comment: I see, thanks :D
It's not ugly, its just every single thing in the level, followed by :removeSelf